# Designing a Stop Watch

Tags: android

I created an application, that functions as a Stop Watch, in which I created Multiple tabs, and then, in the Stop Watch, I use `System.currentTimeMillis()` function to get the time of the system in Milliseconds.
 The function works correctly to display the time, once the stop watch is stopped, but unlike the stop watches that are inbuilt in our phones, that shows the instantaneous values, when I try to implement the similar thing in the application, by using the switch case to get the id's of the buttons pressed, and till the time stop is pressed, I create a temporary variable, and use that temporary variable to get the value of current time using the same previous function `System.currentTimeMillis()`. And, then calculating the value of seconds, minutes, and milliseconds, I write the value on the `TextView`, that I have set up in the layout. But, the program gives error, in this respect, while without using the instantaneous values, the program functions good. Can anyone help me out ?

The code for the basic program is added below -

```
case R.id.start:

    start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //start.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    //start.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    //start.setText("STOP");


    break;

    case R.id.stop:

    stop1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(start1!=0){
        long ans = stop1 - start1;
        int milli = (int)(ans % 1000);
        int millis = (int)(milli/100);
        int seconds = (int)(ans/1000);
        int minutes = (seconds/60);

        result.setText(String.format("%d:%02d:%d", minutes, seconds, millis)); 
        start1 = 0;
        }

        break;
```

This is the code, that was working fine, but when I try the same stop thing, in start too, by creating a temporary variable, called start2, and then getting the time at all instants, and displaying them, the application gives error. The new start code is added below!

```
case R.id.start:
long stop1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long ans = stop1 - start1;
int milli = (int)(ans % 1000);
int millis = (int)(milli/100);
int seconds = (int)(ans/1000);
int minutes = (seconds/60);
result.setText(String.format("%d:%02d:%d", minutes, seconds, millis));
```

The program is not working as of now. Even after pressing the stop button, it isn't showing anything!

EDIT:

So, the code that I am working with now, is the following. And the log cat is below it!

```
case R.id.start:
    if(start.getText().toString().contentEquals("Start")){
    start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    start.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    start.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    start.setText("Stop");
    stop1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long ans = stop1 - start1;
    int milli = (int)(ans % 1000);
    int millis = (int)(milli/100);
    int seconds = (int)(ans/1000);
    int minutes = (seconds/60);

    result.setText(String.format("%d:%02d:%d", minutes, seconds, millis));
    }
    else{
        start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        start.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        start.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        start.setText("Start");
        stop1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long ans = stop1 - start1;
        int milli = (int)(ans % 1000);
        int millis = (int)(milli/100);
        int seconds = (int)(ans/1000);
        int minutes = (seconds/60);

        result.setText(String.format("%d:%02d:%d", minutes, seconds, millis));
    }


    break;
```

The logCat is as shown below:

```
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070): Process: com.example.newapplication, PID: 3070
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newapplication/com.example.newapplication.Tabs}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at com.example.newapplication.Tabs.onCreate(Tabs.java:36)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-11 07:34:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     ... 11 more
```

EDIT:
The new code that I am trying, is by implementing a Thread, and that waits for 10 ms, and then calculates the difference, there seems to be an error, with the thread implementation, the code and logcat are attached below!

```
case R.id.start:
    start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
            sleep(10);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                    }   finally {
                    stop1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long ans = stop1 - start1;
                    int milli = (int)(ans % 1000);
                    int millis = (int)(milli/100);
                    int seconds = (int)(ans/1000);
                    int minutes = (seconds/60);

                    result.setText(String.format("%d:%02d:%d", minutes, seconds, millis));

                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();

    break;
    case R.id.stop:
        stop1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long ans1 = stop1 - start1;
        int milli1 = (int)(ans1 % 1000);
        int millis1 = (int)(milli1/100);
        int seconds1 = (int)(ans1/1000);
        int minutes1 = (seconds1/60);

        result.setText(String.format("%d:%02d:%d", minutes1, seconds1, millis1));   

    case R.id.reset:
        result.setText("0:00:0");
        start1 = 0;
        break;
```

LogCat:

```
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-177
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195): Process: com.example.newapplication, PID: 3195
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6094)
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:857)
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4320)
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10935)
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10890)
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6579)
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3813)
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
06-11 08:47:51.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3195):     at com.example.newapplication.Tabs$2.run(Tabs.java:98)
```

Comment: Which is the error? can we see your code?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute. I will post it along with the question in a minute!

Comment: Is this just one long sentence? What about some paragraphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `case R.id.start:` you save the time in stop1 variable `long stop1 = System.currentTimeMillis();` and set start1 to 0.

In `case R.id.stop:` the if condition`if(start1!=0)` check variable `start1` which is previously set on 0.

The if condition will never return true and that's why you don't see any text in `TextView`

EDIT:

In your new implementation you read `start1` and `stop1` one after another. Both variables will have the same value since the few instructions that pass between the two call of `System.currentTimeMillis()` take less then 1 millisecond to execute. Because of this `ans` will have value 0.

The `NullPointerException` seems to be caused by something else and I can't figure out from the code snippet you provided.

```
case R.id.start:
    if(start.getText().toString().contentEquals("Start")){
    start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    start.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    start.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    start.setText("Stop");
    stop1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long ans = stop1 - start1;
    int milli = (int)(ans % 1000);
    int millis = (int)(milli/100);
    int seconds = (int)(ans/1000);
    int minutes = (seconds/60);

    result.setText(String.format("%d:%02d:%d", minutes, seconds, millis));
    }
    else{
        start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        start.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        start.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        start.setText("Start");
        stop1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long ans = stop1 - start1;
        int milli = (int)(ans % 1000);
        int millis = (int)(milli/100);
        int seconds = (int)(ans/1000);
        int minutes = (seconds/60);

        result.setText(String.format("%d:%02d:%d", minutes, seconds, millis));
    }


    break;
```

Comment: That start1=0 line, was just copied by mistake, even after removing it, the stop is working, but the desired result is still far from being reached.

Comment: You have to save the time in R.id.start case in start1 instead of stop1 variable because you check the start1 variable in R.id.stop case.

Comment: Fine, I get your point now, and now I have tried implementing a Thread, that waits for 10 milliseconds, and then subtracts the values, as I have already written above. Can you please help me with that problem ? The update, is added above in the question only!

Comment: http://www.techsono.com/consult/update-android-gui-timer/ -> See if you can find the answer in this link.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();`  instead of `start1 = 0` at the end of case `R.id.start:`. Because you have a `if(start1!=0)` check at your `case R.id.stop:`. It is the reason why your stop does not work.

Comment: That start1=0 line, was just copied by mistake, even after removing it, the stop is working, but the desired result is still far from being reached.

Comment: "result is still far from being reached" what result do you expect?

Comment: I wish to see an updated Stop Watch, in the sense, the time I press the start button, it should keep on incrementing the instantaneous values, and then as soon as stop is pressed, it should tell me the stop watch time.